# Замена слов в двух строках

Tags: c#, строки

Есть две переменные типа string:

```
st="UPDATE КИ SET Дополнительная_информация = 'One', График_интеграл = 2, Размер_пикселя = 3 WHERE Дополнительная_информация IS NULL;"
st2="testovaia zapis, 23, 57";
```

Строка st будет оставаться неизменной, а три параметра строки st2 будут меняться. Мне необходимо заменить слово One на testovaia zapis, 2 на 23 и соответственно 3 на 57 (или на любые другие слова и числа, которые будут на данный момент записаны в переменную).
Предполагаю, что можно решить проблему так:

```
        string d = "";
        string f = "";
        string h = "";
st.Replace("one", d);
st.Replace("2", f);
st.Replace("3", h);
```

Но как сделать так, чтобы значения из строки st2 записывались в переменные? Заранее спасибо.

Изменил код, взяв за основу ответы ниже:

```
string st2= textBox3.Text;
        OleDbCommand st = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE КИ SET Дополнительная_информация = @DopInf, График_интеграл = @GrafikIntegral, Размер_пикселя = @RazmerPikselja WHERE Дополнительная_информация IS NULL;");
        st.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DopInf", st2.Split(",")[0].Trim());
        st.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GrafikIntegral", st2.Split(",")[1].Trim());
        st.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RazmerPikselja ", st2.Split(",")[2].Trim());
        st.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Может Вам нужен обычный параметризированный запрос?

Comment: Мне в любом случае необходимо считать значения из второй строки и записать их в переменные..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Легче и правилнее будет с параметризированным запросом:

```
SqlCommand st=  new SqlCommand("UPDATE КИ SET Дополнительная_информация = @DopInf, График_интеграл = @GrafikIntegral, Размер_пикселя = @RazmerPikselja WHERE Дополнительная_информация IS NULL;");
st.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DopInf", st2.Split(',')[0].Trim());
st.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GrafikIntegral", st2.Split(',')[1].Trim());
st.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RazmerPikselja ", st2.Split(',')[2].Trim());
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробовал исправить код, но столкнулся с ошибками:

Comment: Ошибка 6 Аргумент "1": преобразование типа из "string" в "char[]" невозможно
Ошибка 1 Наиболее подходящий перегруженный метод для "string.Split(params char[])" имеет несколько недопустимых аргументов

Comment: исправил код st2.Split(",") -> st2.Split(',')

Comment: В вашем варианте стоит учесть, что st2.Split() может вернуть не 3 значения.

Comment: @AntonShakalo Да, вы правы

Comment: @AntonShakalo А что вы имеете ввиду под тем, что может вернуть не 3 значения?

Comment: В остальном всё работает, спасибо!

Comment: @Georg96 если st2 = "testovaia zapis, 23"  или st2 = "testovaia zapis" или st2 = "" ,  будет ошибка

Comment: Ну если у вас будет строка не "testovaia zapis, 23, 57", а "testovaia zapis, 23" - код вывалится с ошибкой на st2.Split(',')[2], потому что в полученном массиве будет только два элемента, индексирование в массиве идёт с нуля, соответственно вы будете спрашивать третий элемент в двухэлементом массиве

Answer (score 0):

Если вы можете изменять st, тогда запишите её как

```
st="UPDATE КИ SET Дополнительная_информация = '{1}', График_интеграл = {1}, Размер_пикселя = {1} WHERE Дополнительная_информация IS NULL;"
```

и сможете использовать string.Format.

Чтобы разбить st2 на параметры, используйте string.Split():

```
  var parameters = st2.Split(',');
```

Не забудьте вызвать Trim() для всех полученных значений, чтобы удалить пробелы.

Точно также поступите с st:

```
 var queryFormats = st.Split(',');
```

Теперь у вас две переменные: одна содержит массив форматов, другая массив параметров для них. Дальше просто сливаем их в одну строку

```
 var rez = string.Empty;
 for(int i=0;i<queryFormats.Count;i++)
 {
       rez += string.Format(queryFormats[i], parameters[i]);
 }
```

Не забудьте проверять оба массива на длину - она должна быть одинакова, иначе не сойдётся и вы получите либо незамененный формат, либо ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

Но лучше всего скомбинировать мой и соседний ответ и использовать параметры.

Comment: Спасибо, попробовал использовать параметры по Вашему совету и совету ниже, столкнулся с ошибками.

Comment: Исправил Split()